# Direct children (Child combinator) selector not restricting to children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

Why do the nested `<ol>` list items receive the `sqpurple.gif` bullet?

```css
ul > li {
  list-style: outside url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sqpurple.gif") disc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>&lt;ul&gt; - parent
    <ol>
      <li>&lt;ol&gt; - parent. Shouldn't this be a number?</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
Windows 10 x64
Chrome v91.0.4472.114
Firefox v89.0.1
Edge v91.0.864.67
```

Comment: due to inheritance

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can you expand on that? If I'm not mistaken then `ul > li` should restrict the targeting to **direct** children of `<ul>` only.

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing as if you write css inside `body { }`, the css will propagate globally to every children. In your case, I see it as `ul > li > ol > li` which is still inside `ul > li`

Comment: targeting is something and inheritance is something else. If you set color to only the body element, all your page will get that color because color is an inherited property.  Same for list-style

Comment: @TemaniAfif Please see the example I added.

Comment: you last example is not a valid one because you cannot have block element inside inline one and background-color is not an inherited property

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see, the blue note from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image? `Note: This property is applied to list items, i.e. elements with display: list-item; by default this includes <li> elements. Because this property is inherited, it can be set on the parent element (normally <ol> or <ul>) to let it apply to all list items.`

Answer (score 1):

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image:

> **Note:** This property is applied to list items, i.e. elements with `display: list-item;` by default this includes `<li>` elements. Because this property is inherited, it can be set on the parent element (normally `<ol>` or `<ul>`) to let it apply to all list items.

To fix this you should reset the `<ol>` to have no image.

The use of `ul > li` is flawed since you should be setting the `list-style-image` property on the `<ul>` or `<ol>`

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sqpurple.gif");
}

ol {
  list-style-image: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>&lt;ul&gt; - parent
    <ol>
      <li>&lt;ol&gt; - parent. This is now a number as expected!
        <ul>
          <li>&lt;ul&gt; - parent</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to puzzle this one out, too, and I've been doing CSS for more than 20 years. The best way to explain it, I think, is that the *rule* is inherited, not the selector. That is, any element inside the selected element gets the rule, and since any `li` accepts a `list-style` property rule, it applies.

As others have demonstrated, the solution is to override for interior list items. You may also be able to implement the `:not` pseudo-selector to be more restrictive in your selector. (Actually, [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14900779/1264804), at least using combinators).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6367905/9730836

You can reset the style to every children (as there is inheritance).

Try:

```css
ul>li {
  list-style: outside url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sqpurple.gif") disc;
}

li * {
  list-style: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>&lt;ul&gt; - parent
    <ol>
      <li>&lt;ol&gt; - parent. Shouldn't this be a number?</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't behave as desired